# Is selective blur (this GIMP's one) available in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, blur

Here's how it looks like: http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-sel-gauss.html

It automatically blurs blurred parts of image, but preserving crisp edges and contrast. Is it available in Photoshop?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The similar tools are **surface blur**, which is mostly same and then there is the **smart blur**.

For reference see:

[Photoshop Filter Effects Reference](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/filter-effects-reference.html)